# Test side effects in unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I would like to know when our unit test code if you need to test side effects. For example if I have a lock with a lockItem(BaseItem item) method and a unlockItem(BaseItem item) method. Should we test the method locks only our element and not another, and like for unlocking ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: In general, the goal is to test anything that could possibly go wrong. If your implementation makes it inconceivable that another element might get wrongly locked, you might decide that it's not worth testing. However, inconceivable errors happen more often than you expect.

Comment: Also, your function should not have side effects. Pretty much ever.

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't test a negative. Meaning don't test what the code doesn't do, test what it does. So there is not a need to test the the method locks more than just the element that it does lock. If you tried to go down the other path it would be like saying "I have a prime number generator, I need to test that it doesn't write to the file system".

Comment: There's a whole concept of negative testing designed around the idea of verifying that forseeable things that shouldn't happen don't happen.

Comment: The negative tests do have some value in this case since you want to make sure that the locking/unlocking function picks the right element. I have had some nasty bugs in the past when lazy code I wrote unlocked things that I didn't really own.

Comment: So I suggest that the test should test that it does lock the appropriate thing, but to test that it does not acquire a lock on anything else seems odd to me. Do you test that no lock was acquired on any other object in the system? Do you add tests each time a new object is added to the system?

Comment: Obviously, it is not possible and not desirable to test all the method should not do (there is an infinite of possibilities as a method doesn't accesses the filesystem or send requests over the network while it is supposed to do a calculation). However if in the case of a locking method, if a use unit tests as regression tests, it is interesting to check that the locking method doesn't unlocks an item or locks more than one item. So when refactoring, if more than one item the method locks or unlocks an item when it should not.

Comment: unit tests fail and fixing bugs happen as soon as possible (with the continious integration).